# Loop over a constant value in gnuplot

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I want to plot a function like:

`f(x)= a * exp (-b *x)`

on gnuplot, for different values of `a` and `b`.

Is it possible to make a for-loop over constant values in gnuplot?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works like this:

```
plot for [a=1:3] for [b=1:3] f(x) title sprintf("a=%d b=%d", a, b)
```

The syntax is

```
for [ variable = start : stop ]
```

However, only integer values can be used this way.

Here is the output for the command above. I used set log y to make it more visible.

[image]

Comment: You can use non integer values like this: `plot for [a in "1.21 1.31 1.41"] 1.*a`

Comment: Not bad! However, this makes it difficult to change the number of values.  I'd prefer something like
    plot for [a = 0 : 100]  f(0.1*a)